# Better way to compare Activerecord for import/update

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Please excuse me if this has been asked and answered and I will go read the information there. I am writing a system that wills tore user name/address among many other things. The name and address comes in on a weekly file feed so we have to determine when that information has changed and then update our system accordingly to reflect the new information. I have to always retain a record of what was what so if you see multiply entries, that is currently by design.

Let me lay out what models we have for this example (fields simplified for example):

```
class Member < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :addresses
  has_many :names
end

class Name < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :member
  # has fields of firstname and lastname for this example
end

class Address < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :member
  # has fields of lineone, city, state and zipcode for this example 
end
```

So I'm wondering what if any resources are available to compare the information in these records to something on a file and then update if needed. Obviously there will be fields in all models that have to be ignored and that aren't on the file.

Would it be recommended to create unstored records and then compare the two objects some how? Do I need to just to string comparisons and then update/add records as need?

I will try to clarify if I'm asking this is in a poor way, obviously not wrapping my head around it very well yet. Thanks in advance for and help and understanding you all can provide!

Mark

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me like you need to create a program (perhaps a rake task that will be called by a cron job) to parse through your file and compare with and update the database accordingly.

I am assuming that the file you are receiving is in some format like XML or CSV so that you can extract records with the associated columns. There are tools to work with particular file formats. See an example of how to parse CSV files at:

[Using CSV Class to parse a .csv file in Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16821787/using-csv-class-to-parse-a-csv-file-in-ruby)

I am assuming that the username does not change, but you want to detect if the address changes. You can iterate through the file and get the username and address for each line and look up the user in the database (via the username) and check to see if the address is the same or different. If the address is different, update it for that record.